# In Rails, show for nested resources not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

I am using nested resources. When I click on a goal that's been created, I keep getting this error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: goal
```

And it directs me to the "params.require..." line:

```
    private
        def goal_params
            params.require(:goal).permit(:text)
        end
```

I'm not sure what's causing this. I can create and show the list. But when I click on a goal I get this error. I'm new to rails and I'm at my wit's end.

My view:

```
<h1>Listing goals</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  <% @user.goals.each do |goal| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to goal.text, user_goals_path(@user, @goal)%></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>


<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@user, @user.goals.build]) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class GoalsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @goal = @user.goals.find(goal_params)
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @goal = @user.goals.find(:id) 
        #also tried goal_params and :goal_id instead of :id
    end

    def new
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @goal = @user.goals.new
    end


    def create 
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @goal = @user.goals.build(goal_params)
        @goal.user = current_user

        if @goal.save
            redirect_to new_user_goal_path, notice: "Success!~"
        else 
            redirect_to new_user_goal_path, alert: "Failure!"
        end
        #to root_path
    end 

    private
        def goal_params
            params.require(:goal).permit(:text)
        end
end
```

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :user do
    resources :goals
  end

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end



    unauthenticated do
      root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end

end
```

My show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @goal.text %>
</p>
```

Comment: What path are you actually hitting to cause the error? And why doesn't `show` show a goal? It appears to `build` one, not show one.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you for the comment. This one: user_goals_path(@user, @goal). How should I change the controller?

Comment: And what goal are you passing in? `show` is for showing a goal, which means it'll have an ID. `build` doesn't save a goal (or show a goal), it creates an unsaved goal (IIRC) so will have no ID. `show` should retrieve a goal.

Comment: @DaveNewton I've changed show function to:  ```def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @goal = @user.goals.find(:id)
 end. ``` still not working. Same error message.

Comment: @DaveNewton Not sure what you mean by "And what goal are you passing in?"

Comment: You're passing a goal when you call `user_goals_path(@user, @goal)`. What goal are you passing in? You might want to take a step back: you can just *look* at the parameters used to make the call, and in the controller you can *see* the request being made.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm very sorry for my noob question: "look" where? "see" exactly where? What seems to be wrong with the code?

Comment: ... In the controller's method inspect the params. Those are the params available for your use. If you're not seeing what you expect then you're not passing reasonable values to the `user_goals_path` method. Maybe a tutorial would be a good idea.

Comment: @DaveNewton OK - I asked because I assumed you were telling me to look somewhere I didn't post. I think you mean this? ``` params.require(:goal).permit(:text) ``` I think this code is ok, but if not, please tell me why.

Comment: I'm telling you to *inspect the parameters being passed in from the request*.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, in the show

```
@goal = @user.goals.find(:id)
```

Should be

```
@goal = @user.goals.find(params[:id])
```

You said you tried with `@user.goals.find(goal_params)` in `show` action and I see it in your `index` action also. This will call the `goal_params` method, which require `params[:goal]`  while your `index` or `show` request does not send to server, only when you submit the form, you will have that params. This is the cause of your error.

Second thing, your `index` should use

```
@goals = @user.goals
```

INSTEAD OF

```
@goal = @user.goals.find(goal_params)
```

Also, the `strong parameters` is used for `create` and `update` actions only to avoid mass assignment to our database. It's not used to `find` a record.

Comment: This is great, thank you! The only problem now is that when I click on a goal, it leads me to index.html.erb (where I have only one line: <%= @goal.text %>) instead of show.html.erb (same: <%= @goal.text %>). When I manually type in url: ...goals/15, the show.html.erb shows the goal text. But when I click on a goal from the list, the index.html.erb generates: undefined method `text' for #<Goal::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007fb86c76f6e8>. How can I click on a goal and go to show.html.erb?

Comment: From your `@goals = @user.goals` in index file, you can generate a list of goals in your index view, and link to goal path

Comment: in your goals index view:
`<ul>
<% @goals.each do |goal| %>
<%= link_to goal.text, user_goal_path(goal) %> 
<% end %>
</ul>`

If it helps, plz don't forget to vote and mark resolve for my answer :) @thebot

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it returns an error: ```undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass``` And replacing @goals.each with @user.goals.each returns a similar error as the one my code returns.